# FC when send image via SMS in android

Tags: android, image, android-intent, sms, send

String message = "HELLO MSM";

```
    Uri sendSmsTo = Uri.parse("smsto:" + "1111");

    Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SENDTO,
            sendSmsTo);
    intent.putExtra("sms_body", message);
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,
            Uri.parse(wallpaperDirectory.getPath() + "/nmc.jpg")); // url

    // intent.setType("audio/mp3");
    intent.setType("image/png");
    startActivity(intent);
```

But when run , app was FC

02-24 21:56:09.881 E       8333     AndroidRuntime                                            Process: com.example.a, PID: 8333
02-24 21:56:09.881 E       8333     AndroidRuntime                                            android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.SENDTO typ=image/jpg (has extras) }

Please help me check !
Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

There is no activity that supports `ACTION_SENDTO` with a MIME type of `image/jpg` on your device.

Note that the MIME type for JPEG is `image/jpeg`.

But, beyond that, there is no requirement for every one of the ~1.5 billion Android devices to have an app that will handle your request. You need to either handle this exception or use `PackageManager` to check ahead of time whether your request will succeed.